# How to disable react material ui DataGrid cell/field checkbox selection?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I have a problem having a checkbox selection and link in the same Material UI DataGrid table cell/field. 
The problem is that one of the cells should have an external link and clicking to that cell, which redirects to another page, checkbox is also being selected. 
 So my goal is to disable checkbox selection on this particular cell/field.
In Mui docs there is `disableSelectionOnClick` api, which allows to check only from checkbox, but not from cell or row. So this not what I want. I still want to have the ability to check from rows except the cell that has a link. In my example provided below, my particular cell name,that should be disable from checking,  is `total marks`.
Code example and [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ng987?file=/demo.js:0-1110)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Link from "@mui/material/Link";

const getTotal = (params) =>
  params.getValue(params.id, "maths") + params.getValue(params.id, "science");

const columns = [
  { field: "maths", headerName: "Maths", width: 130 },
  { field: "science", headerName: "Science", width: 130 },
  {
    field: "Total",
    headerName: "Total marks",
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: getTotal,
    editable: true,
    renderCell: (cellValues) => (
      <Link
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        href="https://www.google.com/"
        sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        {cellValues.value}
      </Link>
    )
  }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, maths: 75, science: 60 },
  { id: 2, maths: 80, science: 70 },
  { id: 3, maths: 50, science: 80 },
  { id: 4, maths: 80, science: 60 },
  { id: 5, maths: 100, science: 90 }
];

export default function ValueGetterGrid() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `event.stopPropagation()` method, along with `field`. forked your sandbox and updated it.

**Live Demo**

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Not working for me...

Comment: share your code in codesandbox. and i will check

Answer (score 3):

For me, `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` does not work, but the following should prevent checkbox selection when column 'Total' is clicked in MUI DataGrid:

```
const handleCellClick = (param, event) => {
  event.defaultMuiPrevented = param.field === "Total";
};
...
<DataGrid ... onCellClick={handleCellClick} />
```

Hope it works for you. See sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-qjkzsv?file=/demo.js